# Why is my drop down menu going behind my slideshow on ie?

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index, cycle

I am hoping that someone out there can take a peek at my page and maybe advise me on how I can get my drop down to show up on top of my slideshow?  Hover over "Quality" to get the menu, and notice it is behind the png.  This shows itself on IE, but works great in Chrome/FF.

http://molded.jasonscms.com/Home.aspx

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Check out this link
http://www.brenelz.com/blog/2009/02/03/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: It works well on my IE9.

Comment: I was already there, and I think I applied that fix!  The parent div of each drop down has a z-index of 3000 applied, and the drop downs z-index is 1000, so it should layer over everything!

Comment: hmm, i think I may have been in compat mode, i removed that and now it seems to work..very odd

Comment: IE9 resolved this common issue, 6-8 are a different story

Comment: Works well on IE for me. May be you need to upgrade your IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was due to my browser being in compatibility mode, I removed that and it rendered out nicely.

Comment: Make sure you have your `doctype` set correctly to ensure IE doesn't go into compat mode. Ex: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent div a higher z-index than the child div and make the parent div's position:absolute and the child div's position:absolute

Like so:

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 2">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index: 1;">

    </div>
</div>
```

This bug doesn't exist in IE9+ by the way

Answer (score 0):

The critical part is to make the menu's parent ( `<header>`) have a higher z-index than it's sibling container which is the parent of the slideshow ( your banner element). The whole issue has to do with how IE treats z-index of absolute position elements and it increases them from top of page going down, unless explicitly set.

You shouldn't have to do anything with the internal elements of the menu this way, the main container will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hack somewhat this:
`#div{
background:#fff;  //desired background color. You can also try transparent.
opacity:0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

just add the properties on ur div tag- it worked for me
CSS:
    #iefix {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is compatibility mode problem but still you should be aware of some people knowingly or unknowingly run in compatibility mode.
That is why you should still fix the problem.

**Give a Parent DIV of menu following style:**

```
#parentDiv{position:relative; z-index:999;}
```

It should do a trick, however z-index must be more than parent div's any other z-index of child divs.